# Authorize the access ability to a user in Oauth 2.0?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect

As far as i known, the protocal OAuth2.0 will bring the access ability from the resources owner(A) to the client. But in the scenario here, I wonder if it is possible to authorize the access ability to another user(B) (After login the user B will access the resources which belong to resource owner A)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Why? Because it is what OAuth is intended to fulfill: delegation of (a secure) access to a user (B) for a resource on behalf of a resource owner (A).

I think the description in [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-17#section-1.2) will be quite straightforward to you:

[image]

> (A)  The client requests authorization from the resource owner.
> The authorization request can be made directly to the resource owner
> (as shown), or preferably indirectly via an intermediary such as
> an authorization server.

> (B)  The client receives an authorization grant which represents the
> authorization provided by the resource owner.  The authorization
> grant type depends on the method used by the client and
> supported by the authorization server to obtain it.

> (C)  The client requests an access token by authenticating with the
> authorization server and presenting the authorization grant.

> (D)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
> the authorization grant, and if valid issues an access token.

> (E)  The client requests the protected resource from the resource
> server and authenticates by presenting the access token.

> (F)  The resource server validates the access token, and if valid,
> serves the request.

Comment: Do you mean, the user B just use a access token which granted from user A and access the resource server directlly ? Eg: User A generate a access token in the backup console of himself , and sent to User B(maybe by email or gtalk), and then user B enter the access token into the application client(should be supported by using client app), to access the resource server ?

Comment: B.T.W, the image you sent step E, how the Resource server know if the access token is correct or not ? Because the access token is stored in Identify Provier side ,right ?

Comment: *Do you mean, the user B just use a access token which granted from user A and access the resource server directlly ?* Yes, and the token is valid for a certain duration only

Comment: *Eg: User A generate a access token in the backup console of himself , and sent to User B(maybe by email or gtalk), and then user B enter the access token into the application client(should be supported by using client app), to access the resource server ?*. Yes (I feel you reworded the same question as the first one)

Comment: *B.T.W, the image you sent step E, how the Resource server know if the access token is correct or not ? Because the access token is stored in Identify Provier side ,right ?*: Of course: remember that the token is issued by the resource owner, that token represents an **authorization access** for a limited period @Kris

Comment: Yes, I reworded almostly, the last one is just give a senario ... But, i wonder access code sent in the email whether it is not safe, this is my worry about .. actaully , i have guessed this method before.

Comment: @Kris where did you read the access token is sent by email?!!!

Comment: sorry ,maybe my english, the first statement, i just want User A give the access ability to User B, So i am wondering how the access token give to the User B, Here my senario, there is no client ...  Only the User A <-> User B

Comment: I want to implement a SSO by OPENID Connect, the resource server is separated from the Identity Provider, Since the access token is issuing from the IDP,and how the resource server determine if the access token is correct or not .